# convert commas in a column of a data set points r

Tags: r, excel, dataset, dataframe, apply

I've imported from excel a dataset. And I have a column 'Height' and I would want to replace the ',' by '.' .
I tried with this command but it gives me error.

```
apply(apply(DATASET$Height, 2, gsub, patt=",", replace="."), 2, as.numeric)
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It is difficult to debug without the original data. Why don't you give us a little sample of heights with `dput(head(DATASET$Height))`? Also, you don't need `apply` here: you can just run `gsub` on your `Height` vector directly. It is the same with `as.numeric`.

Comment: We don't know _how_ you import your data to R, but you should check the `dec` argument in the `read.*` functions to get a correct decimal point from the start. Set `dec = ","`, and they are converted to the R standard `"."`

Comment: It's easier if you use `dec=","` argument when you're importing the data :D

Comment: Thanks for answer. If I add dec="," so R don't import me all the dataset from excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check if it is character. Then, I would split the strings by the comma, then paste them with a dot:

suppose a is what you get with `DATASET[["Height"]]`

```
a <- c("234,23", "2314,54", "234,65")
```

then with `sapply`, you can split and collapse each character element:

```
b <- sapply(a,
  function(string){
    paste0(unlist(strsplit(string, split=",")),collapse=".")
  })
```

Now, you can replace the `DATASET[["Height"]]` with `b`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I had Height like a factor class. With your procedure is perfectly replaced. :D

Answer (score 1):

To recode column 'Height' in data frame 'DATASET':

```
DATASET$Height <- gsub(",",".",DATASET$Height,fixed=TRUE)
```

Any errors? If no you can proceed to convert the column to numeric.
Get errors when converting to numeric? Perhaps you have still other characters besides "," that prevent R from reading the values as numbers. In that case you would need to apply gsub a second time to remove all non-numeric characters.